# ImageView src and background tags when using <layer-list> with a centered <bitmap>

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, layer-list

I have an `ImageView`, and a `<layer-list>` in `/res/drawable/`. This is the layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <!-- This is a 24dp x 24dp PNG -->
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_secondary_arrow" 
            android:gravity="center"/>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="@color/icon_primary_background"
                android:width="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

ImageView has nothing special:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

When using `src` or `setImageDrawable(int)` pointing to the layer-list, `center` seems to be ignored (or at least this is not my desired behavior):

[image: Undesired behavior]

I want to display it as below. This is possible using `background` (or `setBackground(Drawable)`) instead of `src`:

[image: Desired behavior]

The reason I insist is because `setBackground(Drawable)` is limited to API16+, and I'd rather not limit my audience because of this.

So, what is it that I'm missing?

**Edit:** as @pskink pointed below, I was missing `setBackgroudDrawable(Drawable)`. But still, that was an incidental question. I really want to know what's the reason behind the different behavior of `src` and `background` (and the respective methods) in this case.

Comment: in api16- it was setBackgroudDrawable

Comment: @pskink Thank you. Somehow Studio was leaving that method at the very end even when hot typing the method. But still, do you know the reason behind the different behavior between `src` and `background`? I mean, I'd like to know what I'm missing.

Comment: hmm,  your code works correctly the icon is in the center,  small size,  tested emulator 2.2

Comment: I could find that if scaleType is set to fitXY, the behaviour is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ImageView` draws both items at the same size. You can add “padding” to your drawable like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top=“16dp” android:left=“16dp” android:right="16dp" android:bottom="16dp">
        <!-- This is a 24dp x 24dp PNG -->
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_secondary_arrow" 
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="@color/icon_primary_background"
                android:width="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```